# Choose Class in Birt is empty eventhough I have added jar in Datasource

Tags: birt

Even though while creating dataset choose class window is empty. I am using Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2).

[image: Added Pojo class and Dataset class in jar[][1]]

Answer (score 0):

From: http://yaragalla.blogspot.com/2013/10/using-pojo-datasource-in-birt-43.html

> In the dataset class the three methods, “public void open(Object obj, Map map)”, “public Object next()” and “public void close()” must be implemented.

Make sure you have implemented these.

Here is a sample that I tested with:

```java
public class UserDataSet {

    public Iterator<User> itr;

    public List<User> getUsers() throws ParseException {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

        // Add to Users
        ....

        return users;
    }


    public void open(Object obj, Map<String, Object> map) {
        try {
            itr = getUsers().iterator();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Object next() {
        if (itr.hasNext())
            return itr.next();

        return null;
    }

    public void close() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Wahab,
It is working now, but again I have got two below issue.

1. How to set relative path in  
 <property name="pojoDataSetClassPath">D:\NGV_WorkSpace_0.20\ngvems\target\classes</property>

2. How to get request parameter in Open method from controller to service method (in grails context.)